# Unificación de Cantidad por día - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día amigos coders.

Un gusto en saludarlos, en esta ocasión les solicito ayuda para poder solventar una sumatoria total por día, dado que, me atasqué en cuanto a su ejecución.

Contexto:

Tengo una BD, con una serie de transacciones diarias, donde aparecen todos los productos en ventas de esta manera:

```
Código  Nombre      Fecha         CantidadComprada  TotalPagado    Costo  Utilidad 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001      Carne 11/07/2022 14:00         0.5             1.0          0.8    0.2
001      Carne 11/07/2022 12:00         0.5             1.0          0.8    0.2
001      Carne 11/07/2022 10:00         1.0             2.0          0.8    1.2 
002      Queso 11/07/2022 09:00         1.0             5.0          4.7    0.3
```

Busco poder hacer hacer un Sumario total por día, por ende, el resultado final sería algo como:

```
 Código  Nombre      Fecha         CantidadComprada  TotalPagado  Costo  Utilidad 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  001     Carne    11/07/2022            2.0             4.0         2.4     1.6
  002     Queso    11/07/2022            1.0             1.0         5.0     0.3
```

Mi código va así:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

SELECT

DISTINCT
Descrip1 AS [Descripción]
, FechaE As [Fecha]
,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
            TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
            WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad
             END) AS [Cantidad]

FROM
    TEMFAC

WHERE 
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
    AND FechaE BETWEEN '05/07/2022' AND '05/07/2022 23:59:59'
     and codubic = '0010-01' and CodItem = '001' and CodItem = '002'
```

y me arroja un resultado así:

```
Producto         Fecha           Cantidad             
---------------------------------------------
Bisteck 2022-07-05 12:55:26.000   0.5200
Bisteck 2022-07-05 17:35:39.000   0.5250
```

Por ahora estoy tratando de poder hacer un total de Cantidad por producto, pero, como pueden observar, esto no ocurre, claramente este paso me conviene realizarlos para poder ejecutar este otro código:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

SELECT

DISTINCT
Descrip1 AS [Descripción]
, FechaE As [Fecha]
,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
            TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
            WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad
             END) AS [Cantidad]
, [Precio] * SUM(CASE WHEN
            TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
            WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad
             END) AS [Total Venta]
, [Costo] * SUM(CASE WHEN
            TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
            WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad
             END) AS [Total Costo]
, [Total Costo] - [Total Venta] AS [Utilidad]
FROM
    TEMFAC

WHERE 
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
    AND FechaE BETWEEN '05/07/2022' AND '05/07/2022 23:59:59'
     and codubic = '0010-01' and CodItem = '001' and CodItem = '002'
```

Y poder tener algo como el resultado esperado, pero sin la unificación de la Cantidad, no logro avanzar.

¿Tienen alguna guía por favor?
Gracias de antemano.

PD: Sí ejecuté un `Order By`, pero, sigue siendo los mismos resultados, por ende, no me conviene.

Comment: O sea que quieres que se quede divido por fecha y lo que te falta es dividir la suma dependiendo de la fecha?

Comment: No, deseo, unificar las cantidades por fecha....

Es decir, si hay 1000 transacciones para un producto, que existe un solo registro para ese día, que diga 1000 transacciones, el coste total pagado en todas las transacciones y así sucesivamente, como el resultado esperado mostrado arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que tu campo **FECHA** es de tipo `DATETIME`, es decir que toma incluso hasta los segundos (también milisegundos) y no es un valor único, por tanto SQL te está arrojando como output la cantidad final, pero las agrupa individualmente por cada transacción que hayas hecho. A mi entender, la solución está transformando tu campo **FECHA** a solamente `DATE` y usando la cláusula `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT

DISTINCT
Descrip1 AS [Descripción]
, CAST(FechaE AS DATE) As [Fecha]
,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
            TipoFac = 'A' THEN Cantidad
            WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Cantidad
             END) AS [Cantidad]

FROM
    TEMFAC

WHERE 
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
    AND FechaE BETWEEN '05/07/2022' AND '05/07/2022 23:59:59'
     and codubic = '0010-01' and CodItem = '001' and CodItem = '002' 
GROUP BY Descrip1, FechaE
```